# How to make option selected by default in JSP

Tags: jsp, jsp-tags

I am trying to create a drop down with some value selected by default using the following approach , but this does not works

<a:dropdownOption value="group_${dropdownItem.groupId}" selected="${ ('${dropdownItem.groupName}' == 'All groups') ? 'selected' : ''}">
${dropdownItem.groupName}
</a:dropdownOption>

Any suggestions on what should be modified in it ?

Answer (score 0):

Used the following approach to get this done

```
<a:dropdownOption value="group_${dropdownItem.groupId}" selected="${dropdownItem.groupName eq 'All groups' ? 'true' : ''}">
```

Here , i compared the `groupName` of drop down item with the desired group name and then assigned true to selected based on if it has the desired group name.